# Warning: Dependency org.json:json:20160212 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

While i am running android studio below warning appear.

This warning showed after I have added compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:4.0.2' dependency in my `build.gradle` file. Here is a  what Messages console shows me.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160212 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160212 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Information:BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Information:Total time: 3.851 secs
Information:0 errors
Information:2 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Here is a snippet from my  build.gradle file.

```
... 

configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
        }
    }
    configurations {
        compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:4.0.2'
        compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
        compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I don't Know how to resolve this error. please Help me regarding this issue.
Thanx in advance

Comment: Thank You guys for looking into this matter. But Somehow I manage to find the easy fix for this one. As I have said earlier that this issue arises after I have added a new dependency `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:4.0.2' `, well I have just edited  this and added one line of code to it `compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:4.0.2'){
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }`